# Normal form of the Frenet Matrix

Tags: differential-geometry

A book that I am going through states that on reducing to normal form the Frenet matrix in the Frenet-Serret formula, one ends up with the matrix:

$$ K=  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2} & 0 \\ - \sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2}  & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix} $$

$\kappa$ being the curvature and $\tau$ being the torsion of the curve in question.

The term $$ \sqrt{\kappa^2 + \tau^2}$$ is called the angular velocity. I would like to know what Normal form they are alluding to? I am also confused as to what eigenvalues one gets from the Frenet formula matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compute the characteristic polynomial of the Frenet matrix, you'll find that the eigenvalues are $0$ and $\pm i\sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2}$. Now, a real $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ with complex eigenvalues $\alpha\pm i\beta$ can be written in the form 
$$\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ -\beta &\alpha\end{bmatrix}$$ 
by choosing as your basis the real and imaginary parts of a complex eigenvector. This is the normal form the text is referring to. (To verify this: Write $A(x+iy) = (\alpha+i\beta)(x+iy)$ and compare real and imaginary parts.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also one curious thing I noticed was that a certain class of curves called Mannheim curves which are pairs of curves one of whose normal coincides with the binormal of the other satisfy the relation $\kappa = \lambda(\sqrt{\kappa^2 +\tau^2})$, $\lambda$ being a non-zero constant and I see that the term $\sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2}$ props up in quite a few results. Would it be worthwhile looking into this??

Comment: Oops a correction: it is $\kappa = \lambda(\kappa^2 +\tau^2)$